# Headers in node.js - socket io Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain:

Tags: node.js, types, http-headers, socket.io, mime

I'm new to node.js and I cannot understand how the headers work. I'm trying to attach to my project fancybox in my index.html but it doesn't work. I'm using c9.io workspace so it looks like that `<script src="http://space.......c9.io/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>`
I still get the same error in console: **socket io Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain:**

Please, is there anyone who can explain me this as simple as possible ?

my js file

```
var http = require("http"),
express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
     server = app.listen(process.env.PORT),
        io = require('socket.io').listen(server)


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the solution to your problem is a little `type="text/javascript"` that you should add to your script tag, but here's a low down on mimetypes:

[Here's some text](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value) about setting headers when using raw Nodejs.

And [here's the same thing](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.set) when using Express.

And here's [mimetypes on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type).

I'm not an expert, but as I understand it, every file or chuck of info sent from server to client (browser, mostly) comes with this mimetype that basically tells the browser how to deal with the file / chuck.. Your browser is smart enough to handle that file correctly even though he received no headers + he is smart enough to notify you that other browsers might not be that smart.

This is how I'd write it:

```
app.get('/',function(request,response){
  response.set('Content-Type', 'text/html'); // 'text/html' => mime type
  response.sendfile(__dirname + 'index.html')
}
```

Lots of mimetypes are listed [here](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml). But I think you can just google something like "{file extension} mime type" and google will serve you well.

Alternatively, you can use [this little package](https://npmjs.org/package/mime) to change `response.set('Content-Type', 'text/html')` into `response.set('Content-Type', mime.lookup(x));` - x being a string such as 'kuku.mpeg' and mime will return the currect mimetype. I use it to resolve plugins that have many subfolders with different filetypes on each one.

Answer (score 1):

A HTTP header is field that contains information about a HTTP request or response. It helps the server or client identify what to do with the data, whether it be what type of data to accept, how big the request or response should be, the origin of the request, to cache data or not, etc.

In HTTP, MIME headers tell the client or server what the type of data is going to be sent or received. The error message you received probably means that the browser thought it was going to receive MIME type `text/javascript` but received `text/plain` instead.

```
Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain
```

To fix this problem, specify the content type when sending the script file:

```
app.get('/script.js', function(req, res) {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
  res.sendfile('./script.js');
});
```

Note that HTTP headers are not specific to Node.js, but are part of the HTTP protocol.